# Animation Bug during form submit

Tags: jquery, forms, animation, navigation

I have an animated search bar, which works on focus method:

```
$("#search .generic").focus(function () {
    $(this).css("width","320px");
}).focusout(function () {
    $(this).css("width","200px");
});
```

However if I click the search icon, it changes the animation (changes the width from 320px, to the smaller width 200px) on the search input box rather than submitting, then submitting. This is the search-icon image class:

```
$("#search .search-btn").stop();
```

I have a CSS3 animation on the "#search .generic" (input box) which works fine and slides ok.

Is there a means to stop the animation when I click or hover the search-icon image?? To let the form submit? The only other JS I have only the form is a placeholder set:

```
$('#search .generic').attr("placeholder", "SEARCH ME");
```

I would note that a standard enter key works fine for the form post. I  just invision people naturally using the image (as per the designer wishes).

-->
HTML Code (POST UPDATE):

```
<aside id="search">
  <form id="searchform" method="GET" action="/search/">
    <input class="search-btn" type="submit" value="">
    <input class="generic" type="text" name="searchform" placeholder="SEARCH ME">
  </form>
</aside>
```

-->

Any help would be much welcomed :)

Comment: could you post your html markup as well?

Comment: post your code completely. or do a jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

This code stops the animation on hovering over your submit btn!

```
$('#search .search-btn').hover(function() {
     $('#search .generic').stop(true, true);
     return true;
});
```

Comment: Could you explain what the "true, true" is for? Many Thanks

Comment: first: clearQueue
Type: Boolean
A Boolean indicating whether to remove queued animation as well. Defaults to false.
second: jumpToEnd
Type: Boolean
A Boolean indicating whether to complete the current animation immediately. Defaults to false.